# Why knex throwing error binding data into query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, knex.js

Hi everyone can you help me ?, I'm binding data into query and I get response back error like this,  I using express framework and i using PostgreSQL for database with knex ORM

#### My Code

```js
    try {
        const resultDistance = await db('store')
            .select(
                db.raw(`ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'), ST_MakePoint(store.latitude, store.longitude)) as distance`, [
                    req.params.latitude,
                    req.params.longitude
                ]),
                'id',
                'title',
                'owner_name'
            )
            .orderBy('distance')
            .first()

        return res.status(200).send({ store: resultDistance })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error)
    }
```

#### Error Response

```json
    "message": "select ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT($1 $2)'), ST_MakePoint(store.latitude, store.longitude)) as distance, \"id\", \"title\", \"owner_name\" from \"store\" order by \"distance\" asc limit $3 - could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

Comment: Please add more details or which framework you are using, which database.
Here as error says DB client is not able to determine data type of  req.params.latitude,

Comment: @Lucia I use express framework and database using PostgreSQL with Knex ORM

Comment: Solved problem like this  https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2386

Comment: I was about to answer this, but looks like you found my github answer instead :D